# Do materials exist, which act as optical intensity compression?

Tags: optics, material-science

Compressors have been used for long in the audio industry. Such quantities seem to be quite useful for sunglasses fort active sports. Photochromatic prescription glasses tan up with increased ambient light intensity, but the reaction is slow and affects the entirety of the viewing surface. Do materials exist, which compress the intensity of incoming light?

In other words, can we make glasses, with which a person can see both very bright and very dark scenes at the same time? Such would be useful to some sports like mountain biking or skiing, where the intense sunlight blinds the person and prevents them from noticing obstacles.

Comment: What do you mean by compress in this context?

Comment: Presumably the optical absorptance increases with light intensity.